# How to migrate report project from vs2012 to vs2015?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, ssrs-2012

How to migrate report project from vs2012 to vs2015 ? I am getting the below issue

This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the following projects. The project types may not be installed or this version of Visual Studio may not support them. 
For more information on enabling these project types or otherwise migrating your assets, please see the details in the "Migration Report" displayed after clicking OK.
     -  "c:\abc.rptproj"

Comment: It seems like the current version of SSDT in VS2015 only supports database and Integration Services 2016 projects.

Comment: Yeah, found this link which says that SSRS will be available in the future update.http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2015/09/01/sql-server-data-tools-preview-update-for-august-2015.aspx